# How do you take a running count of a factor variable with two categories in r?

Tags: r

I am working with sports data and I want to calculate a running total of goals for each team in a data frame of shots to subtract and get a goal differential at the time of the shot. Suppose for example that my data looks like so:

```
(shots <- structure(list(Team = c("One", "Two", "One", "One", "Two", "One", "Two"), 
           Goal = c("N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y")), class = "data.frame", 
      .Names = c("Team", "Goal"), row.names = c(NA, -7L)))

Team    Goal
One      N
Two      N
One      N
One      Y
Two      Y
One      N
Two      Y
```

So I would want to count the number of "Y"s ("Y" meaning yes it was a goal) and end up with something like this (Unless of course there is more efficient way of doing this):

```
Team    Goal    Team_1_Goals    Team_2_Goals    Team_1_diff
One      N           0               0               0
Two      N           0               0               0 
One      N           0               0               0 
One      Y           1               0               1
Two      Y           1               1               0
One      N           1               1               0
Two      Y           1               2              -1
```

Comment: Are there only two teams?

Comment: Is only the last column needed? Or also the other two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` answer.

```
library(dplyr)

shots %>% 
  mutate(Team_1_Goals = cumsum(Team=="One" & Goal=="Y"), 
         Team_2_Goals =  cumsum(Team=="Two" & Goal=="Y"),
         Team_1_diff = Team_1_Goals - Team_2_Goals)

#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   Team  Goal  Team_1_Goals Team_2_Goals Team_1_diff
#>   <chr> <chr>        <int>        <int>       <int>
#> 1 One   N                0            0           0
#> 2 Two   N                0            0           0
#> 3 One   N                0            0           0
#> 4 One   Y                1            0           1
#> 5 Two   Y                1            1           0
#> 6 One   N                1            1           0
#> 7 Two   Y                1            2          -1
```

Your question title spoke of "factor variable". If you load the data using `data.frame` or `read.csv` (or something similar) it will turn the two variables into factors because that is the default, but it is not often what you really want. This code will still work even if the variables are stored as factors. You might want to consider using the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option to however you are getting the data. Or use the `dplyr` version like `read_csv` among many other options.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short way to achieve that:

```
shots$Team_1_diff <- with(shots,cumsum((Team=="One"&Goal=="Y")-(Team=="Two"&Goal=="Y")))
data
#   Team Goal Team_1_diff
# 1  One    N           0
# 2  Two    N           0
# 3  One    N           0
# 4  One    Y           1
# 5  Two    Y           0
# 6  One    N           0
# 7  Two    Y          -1
```

Here I'm using `with(shots, ...)` as not to repeat `shots$` for each variable. Next, I intuitively use `cumsum` across a nicely constructed vector: `(Team=="One"&Goal=="Y")` is `TRUE` when the first team scores and `FALSE` otherwise, and the same happens with `(Team=="Two"&Goal=="Y")`. Then, however, since things like `TRUE - FALSE` are not really well-defined, what is being done is that logical values are being coerced to 1 (when `TRUE`) and 0 (when `FALSE`), in this way providing the desired result.